# Equivalent code in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

is there an equivalent code in groovy for the following code in java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class Text {

public static void main(String [] args) {

String [] array = {"hello", "world","Pasci","Jenny"};
List <String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
 {
     Random rand = new Random();
     System.out.println("String from list: " + list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size())));
}
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: lmgtfy http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pick_random_element#Groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy's syntax is lighter and not as verbose as Java:

```
def list = ["hello", "world","Pasci","Jenny"]
Random rand = new Random()
println "String from list: " + list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()))
```

**Side note**: Groovy is almost a super-set of Java, meaning, you can write almost *any* Java code in a groovy file and it'll compile and run.